# GitHub PAT‘s for multiple organisations

Tags: github, authorization, personal-access-token

Doing a lot of research I was not able to find a lot that made me be sure that this cannot work.

As it’s stated that *Each token can only access resources owned by a single user or organisation*.

But my question is, whether GitHub personal access tokens can work across multiple organisations or just with one, the one they were created for?

I did a lot of research but that’s the only info i found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The now called ‘classic’ tokens work for ALL organizations your user has access to, which was a security problem. That is why they have now introduced the new tokens, which *can* be limited to a single organization.